# Turning off notifications, notification center and control center

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, ios7

I have an app that I will be running in guided access, rendering it the only thing the iPad is able to run.

I was wondering how it would be possible to turn off:

1. Notifications such as software updates
2. The drop down for notification centre (only available once swiped down from the top of page)
3. The up arrow for control centre (only available once swiped up from the bottom of page).

I have heard that certainly the notifications still get fired while in Guided access.  The second two are more a presumption.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As expected the second two options were resolved by turning on Guided Access.

Still not away of the remaining issue.